# Recursive Oracle query to calculate two values that depends on each other

Tags: oracle, recursive-query

I have this table with materials stock data:

```
Date(MM/DD) |received_qty| returned_qty | used_qty
01/01       |   5000     |    0         |  3500
01/02       |    0       |    0         |  1500
01/03       |   7500     |    0         |  1250
01/04       |    0       |    0         |    0
```

I need to add two more columns to calculate the "start quantity" and the "daily stock", assuming this:

- "start quantity" is zero in the first day, after that is "daily
  stock" from the previous day.
- "daily stock" is "start quantity" + received_qty - returned_qty - used_qty

As you can see, each value depend on each other...

So, the data would like this after adding these two columns:

```
Date(MM/DD) |Start_qty  |received_qty| returned_qty | used_qty | daily_stock
01/01       |    0      |   5000     |    0         |  3500    |   1500
01/02       |   1500    |    0       |    0         |  1500    |    0
01/03       |     0     |   7500     |    0         |  1250    |   6250
01/04       |   6250    |    0       |    0         |    0     |   6250
```

I'm sure these columns can be generated using recursives queries with `start with` and `connect by` clauses present in Oracle, but I'm struggled with the script...

Comment: Use `lag` and be happy. You won't need a recursion here

Comment: Indeed, I would also suggest use of the LAG analytical function

Comment: For what it's worth - this is not how a real inventory system works. You don't have multiple columns specifying "received_qty" and "returned_qty" and "used_qty". You have a transaction table which tells you what's being done, each of which has clear and well-defined effects on inventory - you have a processor that reads the transaction queue and processes those transactions - and you have your inventory, both by location and SKU and corporate by SKU, and you make darn sure that each transaction commits cleanly before you proceed on to the next transaction. Don't ask me how I know... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
Select t.*,
     Coalesce( 
       Sum( "received_qty" - "returned_qty" - "used_qty" )
       Over ( order by "Date" ) ,
       0) as daily_stock,
     Coalesce(
       Sum( "received_qty" - "returned_qty" - "used_qty" )
       Over ( order by "Date" 
              Rows between unbounded preceding
              And 1 preceding ), 
       0) as start_quantity

from table1 t
```

Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94417/13

```
|                  Date | received_qty | returned_qty | used_qty | DAILY_STOCK | START_QUANTITY |
|-----------------------|--------------|--------------|----------|-------------|----------------|
| 2001-01-01 00:00:00.0 |         5000 |            0 |     3500 |        1500 |              0 |
| 2001-01-02 00:00:00.0 |            0 |            0 |     1500 |           0 |           1500 |
| 2001-01-03 00:00:00.0 |         7500 |            0 |     1250 |        6250 |              0 |
| 2001-01-04 00:00:00.0 |            0 |            0 |        0 |        6250 |           6250 |
```

Comment: Hi krokodilko! your query certainly do the trick! Thank you! I'm going to investigate this clause "Rows between unbounded preceding" to fully understand your solution...

Comment: Just ask him to explain it.. stackOverflow is "where developers learn.." after all, and code only answers aren't really what the site wants (because they only give you a fish, they don't teach you/future visitors how to fish) - this answer would certainly benefit from a paragraph or two of explanation, Kroko